# Flutter TextField "Changing the content within the the composing region may cause the input"

Tags: flutter, textfield

I created a new Flutter app and I'm trying to set an initial value in a `TextField` widget using a process I've used before in several apps. Whenever I edit content in the field, the Android Studio Run window displays:

```
W/TextInputPlugin(18696): Changing the content within the the composing region may cause the input method to behave strangely, and is therefore discouraged. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78827 for more details
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18696): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

When I look at the referenced link, I don't see anything there that describes the solution.

To test this, I made a new, clean app with just a `Text` widget and the `TextEdit` widget and I still get the same issue. I'm not doing anything except setting the default value. Ultimately I want to capture changes to the input field and write the value to local storage, but I thought I'd fix this input error first.

Here's the code for my test app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const appName = 'TextField Test';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appName,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: HomePage(title: appName),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late TextEditingController textEditingController;
  String _inputValue = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: _inputValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:
              Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Text('This is some content in a Text widget'),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter some text here'),
              controller: textEditingController,
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

When I add a listener to the controller, I noticed that its firing multiple times for every character I type:

```
I/flutter (18696): Listener fired the e
I/flutter (18696): Listener fired the e
I/flutter (18696): Listener fired the en
I/flutter (18696): Listener fired the en
```

Here's the listener code:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: _inputValue);
    textEditingController.addListener(() {
      print('Listener fired ${textEditingController.text}');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Flutter remakes this `TextField` when too many rebuilds and listening-ins happen on this widget. In my case, I was using 2 `TextInputFormatters`, 1 `TextEditingController`, a validator consisting of 8 different condition checks, and an asynchronous onChanged method which had `_formKey.CurrentState.validate()` at its end. Also, there was a suffix that was rebuilding in response to the state of validation. Whenever I switched focus from this to another text field and then back, the field would stop responding to key taps on keyboard for 1-3 secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add static keyword .

```
 static late TextEditingController textEditingController;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a warning. İf it bothers you don't use computer keyboard, instead use virtual keyboard on the simulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this looks like a longstanding issue that has yet to be resolved by the Flutter team according to this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471. I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

So I met with the same 'problem' here.

I used `TextFormField` widget to be my input.
These logs come when I don't define the `keyboardType` props for simple label input and start typing random inputs.

The soulution I found is when I define `keyboardType: TextInputType.name`, the logs gone for good. I also tested it with `keyboardType: TextInputType.email` and `keyboardType: TextInputType.password`, it works on both.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unfortunately. Note that these logs only occur to me when I type in the Android Emulator via keyboard. If I use the on-screen keyboard these logs do not appear for me.

Comment: @Sven I have same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @MKarimi Sorry, it's been a long time. I don't remember how I dealt with this issue. :( Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

on my side, the issue came about when I declared the textEditingController inside the
widget build function like this

**Wrong declaration of textEditingController**

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();


return TextField(
  controller: textEditingController ,
  decoration: InputDecoration(

      hintText: "hintText",
      labelText: "placeholder",

  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
  onChanged: (text){
    
  },

);  }
```

This issue was sorted when I declared the `textEditingController` outside the widget function like this

**Right declaration of textEditingController**

```
TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TextField(
  controller: textEditingController ,
  decoration: InputDecoration(

    hintText: "hintText",
    labelText: "placeholder",

 ),
 keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
onChanged: (text){

});
}
```

also when setting the `textEditingController.text` I would recommend setting it in the `initState` function rather than in the widget build function as shown below

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  textEditingController.text = someValueVariable;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was doing something similar, declaring `textEditingController` outside the `build` method, but calling `textEditingController.text = val` inside `build`, to set the initial `TextField` value. That should be done in `initState`, not `build`.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same message, and this is how I solved it:

Inside your **TextFormField** I've added the property `keyboardType: TextInputType.text,`
Change it accordingly to your input type (ex: **name**, **number**, **text**, **phone**, etc...)

After that, I've added the function `onEditingComplete: () {<your code here>},`
This allows you to enable any future action after the edition of the text, like changing focus, submitting the form, etc.
Full example:

```
TextFormField(
    autofocus: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Enter some text here'),
    controller: textEditingController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    onEditingComplete: () {
        print(textEditingController.text);
    },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. Disable all settings in Gboard setting > Text correction.

https://github.com/siqwin/mask_text_input_formatter/issues/64#issuecomment-1327205058